# r leaflet popup not showing anything

Tags: r, leaflet

I am ploting data via leaflet in R using

```
leaflet(data=a) %>%
addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(a$long, a$lat, popup=a[,4])
```

which returns:

[image]

but when I have popup=rownames(a), it works:

[image]

Any ideas why? I have the same issue with label (works with rownames, not column values)

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example...

Answer (score 2):

it appears it needs to be type character:

`popup = as.character(a[,4])` works